# Search bar for my blog doesn't show the filtered blogs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, blogs, searchbar

Here is my code, I cannot reach any result from the search bar.

```
const RecentBlogs = ({recentBlogs}) => {

const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
const filteredItems = (() => {
    if(!query) return recentBlogs.filter(item =>{
        return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    })
    
}, [recentBlogs, query])


    return ( 
        <div className="recent-blogs">
            <h2 className="recent"> Recent Blogs</h2>
            <div className="bloglist">
                    {recentBlogs.map((blog) => (
                         <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                            <Link to ={`/blogs/${blog.id}` }> 
                            <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                            <h3>{blog.author}:</h3>
                            <p>{blog.desc}</p>
                            </Link>
                         </div>   
                    ))}
                
            </div>

            <input
             value={query}
             onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
             type="search" placeholder="Search" className="search-bar"/>
             <h3>Items: </h3>
             {filteredItems.map(item => (
                <div>{item.title}</div>
             ))}


        </div>
     );
}
```

I was trying to filter the words from my blogs, but I couldn't. Console doesn't show any error related to this. I'm a beginner, I would be happy for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use useeffect

```
const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  if (!query) {
    const filtered = recentBlogs.filter((i) =>
      i.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilteredItems(filtered);
  }
}, [query, recentBlogs]);
```

or probably you could even achieve it by just adding the filter into your map

```
 {recentBlogs.filter((i) =>
      i.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    ).map((blog) => (......
```